# "Насмарку"

Tags: этимология

Интересно бы узнать этимологию слова "насмарку". Что за "смарка" такая?

Comment: Интересно, является ли украинское слово "марний" родственным с выражением "насмарку". Разбирал текст [Ой пид вишнею](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aox4Wojngk), и задумался. ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исконно русское слово. Сращение предл.-пад. формы **на смарку**, где **смарка** - "счистка" (написанного на доске) (Шанский Н.М. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка). Смарка - отглагольное существительное, таких в русском языке много: варка, мойка, штопка, стройка и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

В книге В.М.Мокиенко "Образы русской речи", 1986 г. издания, дается более подробное описание. Автор утверждает, что первоначально "смарывались", счищались написанные мелом данные при азартной игре в карты или долговые записи. Смарать запись - значит, рассчитаться с долгом.
Таким образом *пойти насмарку* значит подвергнуться стиранию, а в переносном смысле - уничтожению, как такая запись.

Непонятность буквального значения слова привела к расширению смысла оборота и его сочетаемости.

Answer (score 0):

а еще марка, марать, насморк.